# Hebrew tag and unreadable text

Tags: discussion, spam, languages, english, unclear

I saw a question pop up and my first instinct was to flag it as spam. The post was quickly removed. My question is, should this have been marked as spam or could it have been meant for some other Stack platform?

I don't see a user with that name and reputation so I was a bit confused about that as well.

[image: Image of question with Hebrew text]

It contains the body:

> שלום לכולם
>
> זאת בדיקה אני אמחק עוד שניה
>
> תודה וסליחה

Comment: Vote to close as unclear, request a translation from the OP.

Comment: What do you mean you don't see a user with that name? [Here they are](https://stackoverflow.com/users/628659/rotem).

Comment: @TZHX beat me with the link to the user, but when you search "Users" it defaults to the week reputation.  You have to change to "all" to see the rep as disaplyed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks for that info. Reputation on the search page was not 350. Didn't know what I was seeing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone was testing. The text means:

> Hello all. This is a test. I will delete later. Thanks, sorry.

It's not spam or rude, but is not considered an appropriate post on Stack Overflow. Just find a way to get rid of these kids of posts without raising red flag alarms - downvote, vote to close (needs details or clarity), flag as VLQ, etc.

Comment: This type of post should be handled with a "rude or abusive" flag. Stack Overflow does not allow users to "test" by posting stuff to the main site.

Comment: @CodyGray - Well then, the description of the rude and abusive flag should be updated, no? It describes the abuse of *people*, not the system.

Comment: This is consistent with every explanation of the purpose of this flag. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317611, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035, and the canonical network-wide FAQ, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035. I can't update the flag text, but I don't really think it needs to be. @StoryTeller

Comment: @CodyGray - Ah, well if there's a legacy of abusing the notion of "abusive", by all means. Thanks for the links, I'm now able to cast my vote in this discussion too.

Comment: In this particular case, I would say to just handle it as you would any non-English content, since automated translators are unreliable, and even if you do speak the language, the mod who sees your flag probably won't. But...if this kind of thing is posted in English, then please flag away as rude/abusive.