# Is a post like 'assdddsssafffwq' spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, disputed-flags

For example, this post:

[image: example post]

I think posts like this should be deleted immediately. These posts don't help anybody. So the question is, *is that spam?*

I did flag a post like that **spam**, now here is that flag:

[image: my flag]

Okay, disputed. So if it's not spam, what can I do? A mod flag? Or just vote to close a question and flag an answer *not an answer* ?

Also I did flag the example post *not an answer*, but that flag is still pending:

[image: pending flag]

I know that this flag maybe helpful, but I think that isn't enough.

Comment: Just don't use a bazooka to kill a mosquito.  Use the flags appropriately, it is not an answer.  It matters what you use, moderators need to be able to prioritize their work.  It will get removed soon enough.

Comment: @HansPassant: So I asked this question. I'm not sure which flag for this post is correct :P

Comment: @KevinGuan Did you read the descriptions for each flag?  They're fairly clear, and the spam flag makes it pretty obvious that it doesn't apply to a post like this.

Comment: No, it's not spam - since it does not promote self or somthing the user is involved into. It's simply "not an answer".

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Note that this represents my opinion on the matter. It **isn't an official stance, and shouldn't be taken as such.**

Additionally, this doesn't completely apply to cases of already-established users posting gibberish. It's probably better to flag those as NAA and give them the benefit of the doubt.

---

**These are abusive**, and should be flagged as such (rude/offensive). Those flags should be marked helpful (as should 'spam', 'very low quality', and 'not an answer'. They all apply).

Here's my reasoning:

**We are a professional site**. Imagine you're at a conference. You walk into a group of professionals discussing something and yell "ASGFASFABFSSFS" at the top of your lungs.

You'd end up getting security called on you. You'll probably be politely asked to leave, then forcefully made to leave - not because you're promoting or actively insulting something/someone, but because you're being irritating and professionals (who the conference *wants* to have a good experience!) want you to stop.

In the same way, people here should use rude/abusive flags (like calling conference security). **This feeds signal to SpamRam**, the automated security officer that blocks IP ranges that keep doing this. If you don't want that system to kick in on these people... please tell me why.

The people who contribute good content to Stack Overflow are our greatest asset. The people who contribute gibberish are just idiots. Good contributors don't like having idiots around. We should optimize for the good contributors, and let the system kick the idiots out.

Comment: At least it explains why I'm always asked to leave conferences...

Comment: I will start flagging abusive but I do think moderators should accept both abusive and spam flags [unsolicited or undesired electronic messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234032/why-dont-we-treat-rubbish-the-same-as-spam/234035#234035

Comment: uggg, that late added disclaimer is due to your diamond?

Comment: @rene Yes. I tend to mark these helpful, but this was written pre-diamond. I was reading it over again, and noticed that it reads like an official stance - which it was never meant to be.

Comment: +1 also it falls into the "abusive" description of "not appropriate for respectful discourse" (imagine somebody interrupting your conversation and yelling "BLAAAAAAAARGH"). My own personal rule of thumb is: If it wouldn't help train a spam filter, it's not spam.

Comment: My cat did once walk across the keyboard while I was chatting for work.

Answer (score 55):

**tl;dr** You can flag this however you want, but your mileage (likelihood of it being treated as helpful) may vary. You may want to stick to NAA or VLQ.

It's not <strike>really</strike> strictly speaking spam because it's not promoting anything. For purposes of Stack Overflow's spam flags, spam is defined as follows:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

This, by contrast, appears to be someone fighting against a possum and losing the battle.

It is, however, "not an answer." Flagging it as Not An Answer is entirely appropriate here, as is down voting.

For what it's worth, the post in question ([link for 10k users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33668257/2057919)) has been deleted, as it should be.

Shog9 has some good points on this topic [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/conversation/shogs-point-on-flagging-gibberish) and [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/238426). This kind of post often *is* someone "spam probing"—testing to see what they can get away with and how long it takes to get it deleted. So, while it's not spam per se, it's not necessarily an innocent instance of a cat (or possum) on the keyboard, either.

**My answer wearing my moderator hat:** Personally, now that I am a moderator, I would mark <strike>a spam</strike> just about any flag on this post as helpful. It's possibly spam; it's unconstructive to the point of bordering on offensive; it's definitely not an answer; and it's definitely very low quality. That puppy's got to go, and I personally don't much care which reason for deleting it is best when so many of them are at least somewhat valid.

**My advice to you as a flagger:** *As a flagger*, you probably want to stick to "not an answer" or "very low quality." Not all flags are seen by moderators, and the review queues produce some pretty inconsistent results on spam and offensive flags for this kind of post.

Comment: Well, what can I do if there is a *question* like that? *very low quality* ?

Comment: @KevinGuan Good question. In that case, odds are it will get deleted on its own (high-rep users get delete votes, and mods of course can delete on their own). Certainly, you should down-vote and (if you have the option) close vote. It's more appropriate to flag a question like that for moderator attention than to flag a similar answer because questions are harder for the community to "destroy" than answers are. If it's in a popular tag (say, `c++`), don't worry about it - it's going to be toast before a mod sees the flag, anyway. If it's in a low traffic tag (say, `n`), you might flag it.

Comment: @KevinGuan Just to clarify, yes, "very low quality" is the best flag for the question in that scenario. If it's available (which it probably would be with such a terrible post), use that.

Comment: Post like these qualify as "abusive" and should be treated as such.

Comment: @JanDvorak Absolutely. They need to be nuked from orbit. They just don't fit the definition of spam above.

Comment: Just since no one else has mentioned it: the term "spam" is somewhat ambiguous. In its original meaning (from Monty Python), it meant something like "unwanted noise" - which would describe this example. Later it came to mean "unwanted advertising material", but sometimes the older meaning is still used (as in "this spammy error message").

Comment: @SteveBennett True. If that were an email, for example, I'd call it spam.

Comment: We actually had a [conversation about this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/conversation/shogs-point-on-flagging-gibberish) with Shog over in SOCVR. The overall conclusion was: All flags fit (offensive, NAA, VLQ) and [**if it's a new user, it doesn't matter (and spam is plausible)**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=26705146#26705146). So now I usually flag such content from new users (1 rep, no badge, unregistered) as spam since it's probably spam probing.

Comment: @Kyll Interesting; thanks for noting that!

Comment: I see inconsistent behavior (some accepted some denied) when flagging as [indicated by Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/conversation/shogs-point-on-flagging-gibberish). I have voted to reopen

Comment: @PetterFriberg It's reopened now. FWIW, I saw only one declined spam flag in your history. It was on a post like this, but the post was deleted by the same mod who declined the flag. It's worth noting that the post also had an "offensive" flag on it, which is generally *not* correct, and it is tricky-to-impossible for us to validate some spam or offensive flags and not validate all other spam or offensive flags. Probably, the mod tried to decline the offensive flag, and it had the effect of marking your flag declined as well.

Comment: @EdCottrell On the contrary, I would argue that offensive flags are more correct than spam flags for these. See my answer below

Comment: @Undo It's not really accurate (IMHO) to say, "A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse." More like, "A reasonable person would find this content nonsensical and useless." And as I'm sure you know, the "offensive" flag is misused horribly. We see tons of them in contexts where they make no sense at all. It seems like people think the offensive flag should be used when what they're looking for is the downvote button. In any case, personally, I tend to nuke the post in question for garbage like this and not worry much about exactly which flag was raised.

Comment: @Undo P.S. [Shog9's comments here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/238426) sum up my personal take on this these days. The review queues do (as I said above) produce inconsistent results, but as a mod, I'm going to nuke that post regardless and not split hairs about the best reason for doing so.

Comment: @EdCottrell Definitely. I'm just saying that neither offensive, nor spam, flags should be *declined* on these.

Comment: I would like to add that 2 of my latest spam flags were declined on such posts (one 2 days ago and one today). The posts were later deleted (one by a moderator, the other by 3- 20kers delete-votes) and the users were destroyed as-well.

Comment: @Undo No argument there. Burn that thing *down*.

Comment: Find an all mods channel and define some nice rules : ), I do not care about my declined flag... just for future consistent behavior. (tell us you like the red spam tag or the red abusive tag in your console)

Comment: `This, by contrast, appears to be someone fighting against a possum and losing the battle.` +1 for this analogy. :)

Comment: But it is an answer, just a poor one :^)

Answer (score 20):

As Ed said in his excellent answer, it's not spam by the Stack Overflow definition:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

Nor is it strictly offensive, though the wording of the "rude or abusive" flag states:

> A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.

which, as Undo points out, probably does cover this "answer" (for want of a better word) as you wouldn't go round making meaningless noises at a conference.

To make sure that we train the system properly I'd decline (or dispute) a spam flag but accept an offensive flag. That way when real spam comes along the system can deal with it appropriately.

Comment: For a simple flagger could I sum it up as flag offensive (ok with everybody as far as I can see) and if you are afraid of flag being disputed flag NAA