# Show a notification that an answer/edit is being made

Tags: feature-request, notifications, duplicate-answers

Sometimes when a new question pops up and is relatively "easy" to answer it I go straight ahead to typing. What happens when I publish my answer though is that I realise there are already 5 answers written in matter of seconds from one another. They are basically all the same, just said in a different style. I guess this applies for not that "easy" questions to some degree.

**So my suggestion is:** 
Implement a notification, which tells the user that an answer is already on its way. Show this notification to the author as well. This can help preventing multiple almost identical answers to the same question and also could prevent the asker of modifying their question while an answer to the original version is on its way.

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR** Don't worry about whether someone else is posting an answer. Go ahead and write your answer, make it a good one, and post it. Then keep making it better if you can. Good answers are always valuable, no matter how many we get.

If I understand you correctly, you are asking not for a notification that an answer has been posted (which we have), but for a notification that someone else has *started* writing an answer. This is probably not as helpful as you think.

First of all, there's nothing bad about having multiple answers. That's actually kind of the point of Stack Overflow: sometimes, you *need* several answers to get the best one(s).

Second, many of the answers we get on Stack Overflow are not good, at all. Many of them aren't even answers. The fact that someone is writing an answer doesn't mean that it won't be garbage. It might be OP posting additional information in an answer, instead of using the "edit" link. It might be, "Hey, me too, let me know if you find an answer." It might be ["assdddsssafffwq"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310177/2057919).

Third, there's the "fastest gun in the West" problem. What if you get 5 answers in the first 30 seconds, all of which say, "Use `event.preventDefault()`"? Nearly all of those are likely to change *a lot* over the next few minutes. Who's to say which is going to end up being the best answer? We don't want to discourage anyone from writing a great answer out of fear that someone else might post a better one.

Fourth, as @psubsee2003 pointed out in a comment below, there's no way to know how long that post will take to arrive. Users can start writing an answer and then walk away from their computers. We don't want to discourage people from answering because somebody, somewhere, started typing, then took the afternoon off, and left a browser window open.

To sum up, this doesn't seem like it would do much to help raise the quality of the content on the site. On the contrary, it would probably discourage users from posting lots of valuable answers and edits to questions.

Comment: I agree partly with you. What happens, if the OP makes some breaking change in the question while you write your answer ? Wouldn't this make your answer irrelevant already at the time it is posted ?

Comment: @Phantomazi That's always a risk, but again, it's impossible to know that ahead of time. Sometimes the OP breaks the question. Most of the time, OP is just improving something, like fixing a typo, formatting some code, or adding an error message. If you really can post your answer faster than OP can edit the question, the time involved is unlikely to be a big deal.

Comment: @Phantomazi also consider I could start writing an answer and walk away for 12 hours, come back, and post my answer.  Do you want it to show I was writing an answer for all 12-hours?  What if when I come back, I decide to discard the answer I was writing?  You'll have been showing that warning for 12 hours for nothing.  And the same goes for editing.  I can start editing, but I don't have to finish.  I can finish later then post, or cancel.  By putting the message out there, you potentially confuse people.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That is a great point. I'm going to steal that for my answer. :)