# A post looks like gibberish. If I can read the content nonetheless, should I flag it for its content or its gibberish style?

Tags: support, flags

I just stumbled upon this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35620897/2628882): [(screenshot for <10K)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHPZa.png)

My first thought was, that the poster had difficulties with the English languages, but his comments suggest that he does it on purpose.

How should I flag this answer? the content "beneath" the gibberish seems not helpful, so it would either be "Not an Answer" or "Very low quality". At the same time it seems (at least from my point of view) as promoting this "language" via low quality post, so is it spam, too?

So what would be the correct flag for those types of posts?

**EDIT:**

I don't want this question to be perceived as "how to deal with this very minor, rare problem"-question. I did some research on the meta-posts and found nothing that answered my underlying problem/question:

**A post looks like gibberish.
If I can read the content nonetheless, should I flag it for its content or its gibberish style?**

Since the current accepted answer does answer this question, too, I edited the post to make it more general and will be of use for a wider range of "gibberish".

Comment: This looks like a rare Very Low Quality target to me.

Comment: In this particular case, my guess would be that we either have someone with a very poor sense of humour, or someone currently undergoing a "mania" phase of their bipolar disorder. At any rate, stackoverflow.com is  English-only. Full stop. An occasional comment to help someone understand why this site is English-only or to point them to resources in their native language if they're clearly struggling is usually okay, but answers are pretty much never.

Comment: @Gimby So I would primarily "target" the actual content of the post instead of the way it is written for those types of posts? And if the content would be helpful edit the question myself to make it more readable (if I can)?

Comment: @printxdiv0 Its a personal choice. I would only try to salvage something that was not created for the wrong reasons myself.

Comment: It falls into the "gibberish" category. Dispatch it as you would any other "gibberish." We don't need a Meta question for every "how do I handle this particular type of gibberish" problem.

Comment: @CodyGray I had a look at those meta-questions. The ones I checked deal with totally unreadable posts. This one was readable, so it basically aims at "If I can read the content nonetheless, should I flag it for its content or its gibberish style".

Comment: @CodyGray I edited the question to make it apply to a greater scope of questionable posts, while still keeping the current answer valid.

Comment: This is one of the more elaborate trolls I've come across in a long time. They're promoting a limited alphabet for the English language, in order to sell their smaller keyboard, or whatever. Brilliant.

Comment: @CodeCaster http://nnicrosopht.net/Html/Patent.html is hilarious. He is also trying to sell the WinAPI rewritten using hecs for $1000 ;) http://nnicrosopht.net/Html/Hecs/doc/oueruieuu.html

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310177/is-a-post-such-like-assdddsssafffwq-spam

Comment: This looks like a very broken OCR software... it confuses w and v with u's, or maybe someone spelling on a speech recognition software.

Comment: It looks like an attempt to answer to me, so it is all good!

Comment: What I really want to know is **Why the question has not been closed?** There are any one of the multiple valid reasons to close it. **off-topic: recommendations** as it is asking for recommendations, **opinion-based** as it is soliciting opinions and discussion and **too broad**.

Comment: I wish I hadn't seen that...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Situation rectified

Comment: Uuhi don't iou lice the language? I thinc it deserues its ouun SE site.

Comment: @CodeCaster He's not trying to promote a smaller keyboard, he wants to cut the alphabet down to 16 letters to make it more computer friendly. Can someone please create English with 32 letters already, I want 6 new characters.

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for a review audit...

Comment: He probably didn't purchase nnicrosopht.com and got .net instead because `m` is deprecated in his language... he's really paying attention to detail. By the way, here's a rough [toHecs](https://gist.github.com/dsherret/f18db5547be0d0f562d4) function.

Comment: am I the only one who acually went to the site http://nnicrosopht.net/ after reading the post?

Comment: It's astonishing that one can in principle read it.

Comment: @SajibAcharya Iph iou read the connents aboue iou'd knouu that nnani oph us uuent there...

Comment: @TomášZato, I see uuhat iou did there.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Bring back Þ

Comment: @MattBurland If you open a patent on a 32-letter English alphabet, you should make that letter the combination of "ed".

Comment: @JonathanMee, It's actually a replacement for [th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)). So Þat is Þe combination it would replace.

Comment: @MattBurland Quick edit! You meant Þat not Þht. OÞerwise Þe joke will be ruined.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Well spotted. I knew I was going to screw Þat up.

Comment: @DavidSherret You missed the `'w'` in your converter. I've corrected that and used it here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317772/2642059

Comment: I never would have guessed that this question get so much attention :D I hope this "language" won't be the next "thing" ....

Comment: To quote @NNicrosopht: "Iou are loocing at the phuture ou languages lice English."

Comment: @CodeCaster "Promoting"? Do you think he actually believes anyone will look at text in hecs and think "that looks like an improvement"?? (I do actually kind of like w -> uu, if only because it makes the word "double-u" finally make sense...)

Comment: @KyleStrand Oh my yes, he believes it. Spelling-reform crankery gets *much* more ludicrous than this. I've seen someone advocate the replacement of the Latin alphabet with a set of 20-odd *colors*. That had all the same grandiose claims about being the future of writing, too. (No, colorblindness was not considered.)

Comment: @zwol Wow, reading sequences of **colors**? Actually... I'm kinda curious now about how it would "feel" to read a page comprised of a sequence of colors (words could be memorized quite nicely... for the non-colorblind). Well, there's "Creole English", so why not "Crayola English", I guess :D Better idea than the joke language this absolute lunatic tries to push.

Comment: @CamiloMartin This was ~10 years ago and I can't find the website anymore, but it really, really didn't work. Me and my linguistics buddies' best guess was the author had an undiagnosed case of letter-color synaesthesia and had *no idea* that A wasn't intrinsically orangey-brown for everyone.

Comment: @zwol That sounds pretty funny for some reason :)

Comment: To be honest, the poster of the gibberish text kind of reads like theres some sort of mental illness or substance abuse going on.

Comment: They reiterated : https://stackoverflow.com/q/55273322/5468463

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The answer is unclear so anyone stumbling on that answer should have started with a **down vote** first.

When that is done we can start investigating if more is needed.

Considering your flag options:

- Not an answer: As soon as an answer is an attempt to answer a question the NAA flags are not your best option. Many of these flags end-up being declined, even for seasoned flaggers. As the language used is debatable we can figure out it attempts to answer.
- Very Low Quality: This flag has a higher chance of being accepted. Posts that are (close to) gibberish are perfect candidates for this kind of flag.
- Spam: You're correct that promoting your own or a service/product is not acceptable in most cases. At first sight the post under scrutiny doesn't seem to be promoting anything. Spam flags have a big impact, they carry an automatic down vote with them and after 6 spam flags a -100 reputation penalty for the poster. If a spam flag was raised on that answer it could have been declined. *Closer inspection/investigation reveals that the answer is also promotional for their own library*

If promotion happens in comments I would use a custom flag and explain for the moderator clearly what kind of pattern you see that you feel needs their attention.

**tl;dr** Down vote the answer and flag as Very Low Quality.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. My first thought was to flag as "Very Low Quality", which I then did. And it is good to know the gravity of the "spam" flag. +1, and accepted as soon as I can.

Comment: "The post under scrutiny isn't promoting anything though." Eh, it's gibberish, you never know - maybe they *are* trying to promote something and spectacularly failing to get it across ;)

Comment: It is *definitely* promoting something. [Their company](http://nnicrosopht.net/Html/Hecs/index.html) sells I++ and UUindows. The *entire answer* is promoting their library or whatever the heck it is.

Comment: @CodyGray noted, and slightly changed the wording of my explanation of the spam flag.

Comment: @CodyGray kudos for reading through that gibberish, quite a poor way of advertising something I'd say :) Its very low quality spam.

Comment: @Gimby I don't know about that. At the very least, I'm intrigued about the product, despite how ridiculous it appears to be.

Comment: A couple of quick whois searches shows the domain nnicrosopht.net that seems to be advertising UUindows has a registrant that is fond of registering domains with phonetic spelling and `"nn == m"` and `"uu == w"` substitutions.  Strange.

Comment: @jrich It is not that strange, these people think they have created a new language that is superior to English. They probably sell "translations" of other products. Well, I guess that's the strange part. :-)

Comment: As @CodyGray points out - if you translate the questioned post into correct English, it is really nothing more than: *Use our [library](link to outside source). It should work for you.*

Comment: @JRichardSnape how did you locate the other domains from the same registrant

Comment: @MageXy resist the spam friend, resist.

Comment: @CodyGray Rather than a company trying to sell something, it appears to be one guy trying to get people to use his joke language / API / interface.

Answer (score 14):

(Translation of [rene's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317672/2642059) for Hecsidecinnal folks reading those gibberish English posts: http://ideone.com/7v7UmQ)

The ansuuer is unclear so anione stunnbling on that ansuuer should haue started uuith a **douun uote** phirst.

Uuhen that is done uue can start inuestigating iph nnore is needed.

Considering iour phlag options :

- Not an ansuuer : As soon as an ansuuer is an attennpt to ansuuer a cuuestion the NAA phlags are not iour best option.Nnani oph these phlags end-up being declined, euen phor seasoned phlaggers.As the language used is debatable uue can phigure out it attennpts to ansuuer.
- Ueri Louu Cuualiti : This phlag has a higher chance oph being accepted.Posts that are(close to) gibberish are perphect candidates phor this ci
  nd oph phlag.
- Spann : Iou're correct that pronnoting iour ouun or a seruice/product is not acceptable in nnost cases. At phirst sight the post under scrutin
  i doesn't seenn to be pronnoting anithing.Spann phlags haue a big innpact, thei carri an autonnatic douun uote uuith thenn and aphter 6 spann phlags a - 100 rep
  utation penalti phor the poster.Iph a spann phlag uuas raised on that ansuuer it could haue been declined. *Closer inspection / inuestigation reueals that the a
  nsuuer is also pronnotional phor their ouun librari*

Iph pronnotion happens in connnnents I uuould use a custonn phlag and ecsplain phor the nnoderator clearli uuhat cind oph pattern iou see that i
ou pheel needs their attention.

**tl; dr** Douun uote the ansuuer and phlag as Ueri Louu Cuualiti.

Comment: Are you giving us the opportunity to practice rene's advice?

Comment: @CodyGray LOL, sure if you like :) Just my attempt at humor.

Comment: I really like the word "Cuualiti," btw. It is a little known fact that the English language has always suffered from a dearth of U's. Obvious improvement!

Comment: @CodyGray I know it's not cultured to laugh at your own joke, but every time I read this post I can't stop laughing: "phlag as Urei Louu Cuualiti" I'll never be able to click that button again without an hearing: "phlgue as youree leu quealitie"

Comment: Can't we could just change it to "Ueri Louu Cuualiti"? No one knows what those descriptions mean anyway. It's a shame that "Not An Ansuuer" is still boring.

Comment: C++ instead of a one-liner in a high-level programming language (like a single statement in Javascript). Do you also kill flies with cannonballs?

Comment: @CamiloMartin You should revisit C++ sometime. I think you'll find that C++11, 14, and 17 have fitted C++'s powerhouse framework with many of the conveniences of high level languages.

Comment: @JonathanMee C++ still has manual memory management and macros, right? And compile times that could only be sped up by keeping Moore's law true for another few decades?

Comment: @CamiloMartin: Manual memory management is still an option, but you call use shared_ptrs and auto_ptrs to have objects be automatically deleted by reference counting. Macros are technically valid C++, but aren't good style. The compile times still suck though. There are plans to create a module system to fix that eventually.

Comment: @JoshuaSnider Thanks for the info. I still think C++'s legacy is what's holding it back, but I admit it's still the top choice for that same legacy/tooling.

Comment: @CamiloMartin I'm not sure how fair the compile time complaints are here. As you say pre-C++11 the only reason to use C++ was to write programs designed for speed and power, typically huge beasts. If you're comparing those compile times to the compile time for a Java Applet, well... you're comparing Applets to Oranges. As far as the legacy stuff... that really is the beauty of the current language: In my main engine I use the "legacy" pointers and avoid any of the overhead, but for my GUI I can relay on all the conveniences of modern languages, *but I don't have to switch langauges.*

Comment: @JonathanMee Just personal opinion, but C++ is not much more than 1.5x, maybe 2x the speed of languages that take a lot less time and effort to write, debug, and patch. Sure, if you have a team of 1k people to make a game engine whose selling point is being 5% faster than the competition at merely a few more millions of dollars and years in development...

Comment: @CamiloMartin I don't get your point. Are you saying that Javascript should replace C++? Note that most to all implementations of javascript engines are written in C++. The code shown by Jonathan will compile and perform well in all languages I can imagine of, why we are then talking about performance here? It is a joke, imo a good one!

Comment: @hek2mgl To a certain extent, the expertise required to produce current state of the art JS compilers transcends C++, yes, it's written in C++, but also assembly for the more impressive parts of it (like turning the JS into bytecode internally). I'm pretty sure the only reason so much is done in C++ is because it's easier to find talent in C++ (in numbers a big company needs to hire), but if you were to do a cold analysis of C++ vs. Rust/Ocaml or even C#/Swift, C++ fights against the developer a lot more than these, which IMHO are better designed and run just as fast.

Comment: (*unless* you're going to add a layer of assembly optimizations into C++ code like the most impressive C++ projects do, in which case you can't compare C++ against others, but pure C++ is bound to be at most 3x the speed of JS in number crunching, [and I'd say half than that](http://asmjs.org/), and certainly on par with anything that also compiles to binaries like Rust/Ocaml)

Comment: @CamiloMartin Honestly, I'd be interested in learning more about Rust/Ocaml, if they have their own memory management? But I don't know if I'd bother until I had someone paying me to do the learning. As I said, I think C++11 and greater you'll find to have the simplicity of the higher level languages, combined with the power and speed of a lower level language. Possibly Rust/Ocaml do as well?

Comment: @hek2mgl I think the point was being made that C++ was simply not the best choice for prototyping something so simple, that would normally be relegated to scripting languages. I was trying to make the point that C++11 and higher was approaching the ease of use of some of these higher level languages.

Comment: C++ is actually one of the languages I never wrote a program in. Not even a hello world one. It sounded odd for me to suggest javascript as an alternative here and I missed to see the advantage. But hey!, it's meta.... Aehm what was the original topic?... :)

Answer (score 6):

The post is an part of an elaborate troll (as several have pointed out in comments). I think the correct response is to raise a flag for the moderators. They would presumably at least temporarily ban the account from posting, and might delete it. Right?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not understandable. It should be flagged for the moderator attention.

With further investigation we understand that it is wrote with an unknown alphabet. That should be accepted as answering in a foreign language. The answer should be deleted and the owner of the answer should be encouraged to answer with the current English alphabet.

If someone asks an alternative English alphabet in a further question somewhere on Stackexchange, he can legitly give a reference to his own alphabet as an answer. But again, if it is an English-only QA site, he should write his answer with the English alphabet, not with incognizable own alphabet.

Answer (score -2):

I do think, as the accepted answer suggests, That mark it as low quality. It is very clear that he did it on purpose. For those who Disagree I would tell them that no one, not even a 3yr old can be confused in the spelling of 'of' more than 5 times. Low quality tag is for the same purpose like the situation is now. Gibberish answers should not be tolerated and flagged instantly. This is a good open discussion for future references.

Answer (score -10):

If an actual attempt to answer (as this appears to be) is in broken English, but you can understand it, you should edit it to be proper English.

Comment: The only sensible comment here.  The situation is nothing more complicated than that: **the writer, who's English is actually perfectly good, just has bad spelling**.  As Brian very sensibly says, just **click the frickin' edit button, and fix the spelling**.  Given the incredibly low language skills in general of the anglosphere, it's crazy to give anyone a hard time about some bad spelling, good grief.

Comment: Sure, if the writer was just being a 10yr old smarty pants and typing in pig latin, sure.  if you think that's the case, for goodness sake state that clearly on Meta, it is the germane point.  Don't talk in circles.

Comment: General bad spelling - yes agreed. But the specific example in question - no. The mentioned example is clearly *not* a case of bad spelling; they explicitly advertise their use of a new language, "*the phuture ou languages lice English.*"

Comment: I really like that idea. Fixing the spelling would extinguish the intended advertising effect - rendering it just low quality :-)

Comment: @OhBeWise It's obvious that the user intended for it to be some warped version of the English language, but that's no reason not to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps, but would fixing it be of any worth? Even fixed it wouldn't say much more than "*try our product*", imho. (Side note: I wouldn't be surprised if the product proposed as a solution is also in the same broken language. Talk about niche learning.)

Comment: @OhBeWise I don't see anything that looks like "try our product" in the answer, only in the comments.

Comment: We should distinguish the example case, which was intentionally written in nonstandard orthography by a spelling-reform crank, from the _much more common_ case where someone doesn't speak English all that well. This is the right answer for when someone doesn't speak English all that well.

Comment: (If you feel like trolling the spelling-reform cranks, I suggest converting their writing to [Shavian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavian_alphabet).)