# What should I do about abuse discovered in a post's revision history?

Tags: discussion, abuse

Today I encountered a post [whose revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41214228/revisions) shows that a string of characters, "YT", was repeated to circumvent the "too much code" warning. In these cases, I understand this as abuse, as [explained in a Meta answer by Undo♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310177/is-a-post-like-assdddsssafffwq-spam/317611#317611). Per that post:

> **These are abusive**, and should be flagged as such (rude/offensive).

My question then is: do I edit it out (as someone already did) and move on (maybe leaving a warning), or flag as abusive and keep it as it is (then "punish" the user for being abusive)?

Comment: "This includes posts that contain *no useful content at all*" - [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor)

Comment: @hichris123 Thanks for the link. From there: *If an otherwise valid post contains vulgar words as an expression of frustration, edit the bad part out instead of flagging the entire post as rude or abusive.* - I gather I should just edit and move on? But I personally feel that trying to circumvent post rules should be noted in some way

Comment: Feel free to throw a downvote or close vote on it; if they have to circumvent the system, their question is likely not the best quality.

Comment: @leaf From my post: *do I edit it out (as someone already did)* - I'm asking about future incidences

Comment: @hichris123 Agreed, but in my honest opinion, I feel like noting this down (by means of, say, flagging) for future reference would be best

Comment: Add a comment saying this is undesirable behavior? (It's the first time this user has done so.)

Comment: @RadLexus So just editing it out with a comment warning?

Comment: Yeah. I wonder why the user felt this was necessary, though. Would the original post *sans* YT's have triggered one of the automatic Low Quality filters?

Comment: Just a note @JoshCaswell - I saw it *prior* to editing. Someone else *did*, so I was wondering what I should do

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, then. You quoted the post saying what to do about stuff like this: flag.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I wasn't sure because in this case there was a legitimate question (it was unclear by my question, sorry) and then I saw someone edit it out and move on. That made me wonder - do I flag or edit and move one. By the answer I gather that I should edit and move on in this case.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If the post has already been edited at the time you decide to flag it, *do not flag it*. The abusive content has already been removed; the post is no longer abusive, and therefore should no longer be flagged as such. It's still at any rate a terrible question and should be handled appropriately.

As egregious a violation of rules as this was, we don't do punishments for this sort of thing. If you think the user could use a stern warning from a moderator, you can send this feedback in a custom flag, and we'll act as we see fit. But please don't take matters into your own hands. Bad user behavior is something that should only be addressed by a moderator.

Keep in mind though that there *is* an attempt (if again a terrible one) at a legitimate question, and furthermore, it's at the start of the post body and not being actively obscured by the garbage content. Editing it out is preferred, especially since you have full editing privileges and it's easy enough to remove a single giant paragraph at the end of the post. Even if you did flag it as abusive in its original state, it's likely a moderator would have just edited it out the same way, and cleared your flag, causing it to be neither helpful nor declined, but disputed. Despite what the label "disputed" might suggest, this is a perfectly normal outcome and nothing to be concerned about.