# Let's get aligned on how spam flags can be used

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, rude-or-abusive

Recently, I've noticed some contention — and simple miscommunication — over when 'red' flags ('spam' and 'rude or abusive') should be cast on Stack Overflow, and how moderators should handle them. Here's what we're talking about:

[image: top of the flag box, showing spam and RA flags]

This really shouldn't be a surprise. Flags in general, and especially spam/rude flags, are a very niche area of the site for most folks. Additionally, Stack Overflow has [a whole bunch of moderators](//stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). At these scales, clear communication and coordination becomes difficult.

I'll keep it short. I believe we all agree that spam ([skin care, anyone?](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/60393)) should be flagged as spam — so we don't need to debate that. I've picked out the areas that moderators, and the community, don't seem to be aligned on:

- **red flags** on **gibberish** - including keyboard mashes, like [this one](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/60480). There's prior discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234032/215468), but as recently as this week I've seen a moderator rejecting the conclusions reached there and handling flags differently.
- **spam flags** on **gibberish** — assuming red flags in general are appropriate on keyboard mashes, are *spam* flags kosher? (Read the facts section before deciding)
- **spam flags** on **abusive posts** — like [(NSFW) this](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/60485). If the point of a post is to compare the OP, OP's mom, Java, Trump, or any number of targets to human and/or equine excrement, I suspect we'd agree that an abusive flag is warranted. Is a spam flag kosher?

I'd like to ask the community's, and others moderators', opinions on when and how these should be cast and handled. The goal here is to reach agreement, if not consensus, on how these should be used, and to create a clear reference for users and moderators alike.

To help in this, here are some facts:

1. The system treats these two flags **entirely identically**. There is no difference in how signal is fed to blocking mechanisms, how they're prioritized in the flag queue (the URL filter parameter is literally named `spamoffensive`), or anything other than pronunciation. The only difference is the label that shows up in the flag queue.
2. Shog's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/215468) supports a philosophy of "gibberish is bad, just delete it". It's easy to extend this to "don't overthink the flags, just handle the content"
3. Community projects, [like automated flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/215468), would require a *lot* of work to respect any kind of forced dichotomy between the two flag types. From the perspective of these projects, there's no gain to be had from forcing the 'correct' flag be used on posts — just a ton of work. See [Pops' comment on the matter](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35745740#35745740):

   > It's... hard... to argue in favor of writing an algorithm and making a bot spend time calculating which of the two flag types to use when they are, in actuality, the exact same flag. It's not even Coke vs. Pepsi, it's Pepsi vs. a second bottle of Pepsi that's using a different but still valid Pepsi logo.

Comment: I've seen a misconception before that some mods decline abusive flags on gibberish because they vaguely think it confuses SpamRam, which isn't the case.

Comment: well, if spamRam does block users who habitually post gibberish, no harm done I guess...

Comment: Personally, where it's obviously spam/rude I'll cast a binding flag and where it's obviously not I'll decline it. I tend to dispute the cases where I can see why someone cast a flag and from their POV it's most likely valid but actually it's not. Another consideration is that helpful spam/abusive flags on posts also make that post a possible candidate for audits which affects things further down the line.

Comment: @JonClements The last part of that sounds like a valid argument to fix/adjust the audit system, if it's causing issues.

Comment: @JonClements a cat on the keyboard is an excellent audit, isn't it? Better than those cases where a mod had to dig through someone's deleted history before arriving to a conclusion.

Comment: Why are you equating a programming language to people?  The language can't get offended, and the compiler gets offended by any manner of syntax errors that appear in legitimate questions and sometimes answers.  Let's keep the "offensive" flag limited to personal attacks on people.  Just because technical criticism of language rules, tools, or coding styles is poorly worded doesn't make it automatically wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt A weak attempt to cover the bases. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22895303/1849664 (NSFW)

Comment: @Undo: Yeah I don't see how that requires a moderator flag.  It's clearly non-constructive, because it doesn't make any technical points, but it's childish rather than offensive, and rude only in the sense that wasting peoples' time and screen space is rude (but then I don't think I should go around flagging ever question that I consider a waste of time).  The low quality queue would handle it just fine.  Same with random keyboard noise.  Same with copy+paste a random paragraph from King Lear.

Comment: @BenVoigt "Inappropriate for respectful discourse" pretty much covers that example, right there in the flag description.

Comment: I'm missing some the idea if gibberish (cat on keyboard), users with other reasonable post should not be red flagged https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=26705146#26705146 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317611/5292302

Comment: @PetterFriberg Worth consideration, but [as Art points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345332/lets-get-aligned-on-how-spam-flags-can-be-used?noredirect=1#comment456224_345333) the data we have says that those cases are outliers.

Comment: So if the system treats these two flags entirely identically, what's the point of having the two different flags? Why not just have one red flag for *spam/abusive*?

Comment: Purpose is for the benefit of flaggers, @DJMcMayhem - same reason we have both NAA and VLQ. You want folks who see a problem - especially a *very very severe problem* - to not have to think very hard before raising a flag.

Comment: @Shog9 that seems counter intuitive. If you don't want us to have to think too hard, give us *one* flag type ("harmful crap"), not two. Giving a choice makes it much more confusing for everyone involved. Both the flaggers and the mods who need to deal with the flag. Plus, as I understand, rude/abusive flags block posts from being used as audits (which makes sense) while spam flags do not. That's a non-negligible difference.

Comment: Doesn't *block* posts from being used as audits, audit-generators simply ignore RA flags, @terdon. As for being less confusing to have a single "bad things" flag, depends on your perspective: if you already *know* the rules, if you already know what the community deems unacceptable... Then a single flag is fine; if you don't, then a broad "everything bad" flag doesn't hint at what you should be looking at either. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340866/is-there-any-reason-to-keep-the-very-low-quality-flag-if-not-can-we-remove-i/340905#340905

Comment: @Shog9 but don't audit generators use spam flagged posts? If so, doesn't that mean that flagging offensive stuff as spam would actually increase their chances of being used as audits? I see your point about its being confusing. Not sure I agree, but I am sure that you've spent far longer thinking about this and from a more global perspective, so I'll take your word for it.

Comment: My argument is essentially that it's confusing for folks who raise hundreds of flags and thus repeatedly encounter cases where a given post is arguably spam *and* rude, or rude *and* VLQ, or... Moderators shouldn't really care; if it's obviously worth validating the flag, then it doesn't much matter why - the problems (both with flag confusion and with audits) tend to arise from scenarios that are extremely *subtle* (plagiarism, spam "seeding", etc.). When moderating I use rude/abusive for just about everything, and then destroy the author too - or I take no action at all. No half-measures!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I vote the following:

- **Red flags on gibberish** are okay (handle as Helpful). Do we really want "sdfiushrf;usrgbsrilbslfibsl.eifub!" sticking around the site for longer than necessary? Red flags put the ability to remove these posts in the hands of a much wider scope of the community than community or moderator delete votes alone, which is essential to getting these posts removed.  Additionally, the description of the rude/abusive flag is "inappropriate for respectful discourse" - and I'd like to see the discourse where jumping in and yelling unintelligible noises is respectful.
- **Spam flags on gibberish** are okay (handle as Helpful). If we accept rude/abusive flags on gibberish, we should accept spam flags on it - there is *literally zero* difference between the two. It doesn't make sense to me to enforce a mostly-arbitrary standard of "we accept this flag when you submit it *this* way, but not *this other* way" - which is essentially what's happening with spam vs. rude/abusive.
- **Spam flags on abusive posts** are also okay (handle as Helpful). See previous - given that there's no difference, is there any point in not accepting both types of flag?

It's also worth noting that [M.A.R. is correct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345332/lets-get-aligned-on-how-spam-flags-can-be-used#comment455987_345332) - I have also heard of cases of one or other type of flag being declined because of confusion around SpamRam. SpamRam handles both flag types identically in every way.

Comment: This is pretty much how I've been approaching these flags for years. If someone flags obvious spam using something other than a spam flag, I'll still delete it as spam and mark the flag as helpful. Same with offensive content. I don't care what complete gibberish is flagged with, as long as it's flagged for removal somehow.

Comment: SE should add a red flag, "Pure Nonsense -  Just get this thing out of my eyes".

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: Yeah and everyone will start using that as a super downvote.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree, it's an awful suggestion. We should all flag Bhargav's comment as "rude or offensive" to communicate this.

Comment: The fact is, gibberish is neither spam nor rude/offensive, and importantly IMHO not "harmful". Gibberish is just noise/nuisance that should be deleted for sure, but not as a matter of urgency requiring moderator intervention. VTC or downvote/VLQ can handle it quickly enough.

Comment: So "sdflibsfdlseflseubf!" is appropriate for respectful discourse, @Bohemian?

Comment: @Bohemian any chance that a herd of robots might cause such a VLQ/NAA flag to be missed with the result of the gibberish staying while a moderator could have handled the case in a second or left it to flaggers to deal with? How much time do these posts take off the moderators' time budget?

Comment: @Jan not that long, but there's a 100 point rep penalty for spam that's upheld by a moderator, and that's seems harsh for "being foolish" (without being pernicious)

Comment: @Bohemian It doesn't seem harsh to me, given they are doing something they full well know harms the readers - even if there are things that harm the users in far worse ways. 100 rep isn't that much, and you can't assume good faith here.

Comment: @Bohemian considering all users I've seen so far posting gibberish are unregistered of have only 1 rep, the -100 penalty doesn't do anything anyway.

Comment: @Floern except for cases of vandalism, which we don't flag as abusive anyways, but opt for a rollback instead.

Comment: @Bohemian Stats: 96.54% of users caught by SmokeDetector posting gibberish in the past two or so years had one rep at the time of the incident.

Comment: @Bohemian Further stats: 99.24% of users caught by SmokeDetector posting gibberish in the past two or so years had under 100 rep at the time of the incident.

Comment: Point being, the 100-rep penalty doesn't apply to the vast majority of these users; further, the majority of the users it does apply to won't get the full penalty. There were 22 users who would have had the full penalty applied, and at that point users *really ought* to know better.

Comment: @ArtOfCode unless it's literally a cat on the keyboard, in which case - can they plead for forgiveness (get the rep back with a mod flag)?

Comment: Probably depends how lenient the moderators are feeling, @JanDvorak

Comment: All ok but maybe some slack to users that have other reasonable posts and post gibberish (don't happens that often but if) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=26705146#26705146

Comment: I'm curious as to one posts gibberish accidentally. A poor attempt at self deletion? My guess would be that plenty of the high rep cases are ragequit vandalism.

Comment: @JanDvorak Moderators have ways to revert the 100-rep penalty (and IP blocks, IIRC) if someone comes back with a story. Personally, I've seen it happen that a gibberish poster comes back with an excuse... maybe twice, and that's a stretch. The usual procedure with gibberish from established users is to delete and clear sessions; usually it ends up being a forgotten session on a library computer.

Comment: @Bohemian VLQ _is_ a flag for moderator intervention.

Comment: @josh but it ain't a "red" flag

Comment: @iBug Red flags was deliberate

Comment: How about **Rude or abusive flags on spam**?

Comment: In this case, what is the benefit of keeping separate categories for the flag types in the UI?

Answer (score 57):

Is the case that we have two options which represent in reality just one action?  If that's the case, then we should look to unify these two flags into one to reduce the confusion around them.  That is, **there is *one* "spam" flag type** which encapsulates posts which are advertisements only, rude, abusive, or otherwise inappropriate for discourse here.

This eliminates the ambiguity of having two flags by only having one flag.  There can be no further confusion as to which flag should be processed, and whether or not it makes sense to process it.  This also helps moderators in a sense to eliminate any extraneous thinking about the matter; if it's truly not something we want here, then it's fine to remove it.

This does also mean that a large chunk of this sort of moderation moves to essence to the community-at-large; enough of these sorts of flags trigger automated effects or punishments against user accounts, and there may be some angst against that sort of reaction to how user accounts are punished.  However, I don't think that this is a bad thing; regardless of the circumstance, we are all responsible for our own accounts and are responsible for ensuring the content we post is what we intend to and is respectful.  This means that you can't just say, "Oh, my 10-month old daughter hit my keyboard and submitted this question.  I'm sorry!"; you have to be more responsible with your account.

Comment: "If that's the case, then we should look to unify these two flags into one" - it's on the roadmap already.

Comment: ... but that roadmap seems to be a 6-8 week (read: 'month') scale one, at least. I'd love to see it happen; in the meantime we need some sanity in how we handle these.

Comment: @JanDvorak:  If that's the case, this *almost* makes this discussion moot.  The issue is one of ambiguity and confusion; if this is already in the works, then there's little input we can add to it.

Comment: @Undo:  In the meantime, my preference is listed above.  Let two be one until the system agrees with the notion.

Comment: Absolutely. That comment presents my view in a way better than I could have said it.

Comment: totally agree. There is also a wider definition of spam, which is likened to trolling.

Comment: On the same line, the VLQ and NaA flags should be combined.