# User keeps adding link to some "Java expert chat" page in every answer

Tags: discussion, spam

In the past few hours I've noticed a user adding the following sentence containing a link to each of his answers (also some comments):

> btw, here you can get some more help www.javachat.co

This currently spans across ~18 answers over the last ~11 hours and leads to a "Java expert chat" site. The user has no visible affiliation with this site, so it seems like spam to me.

Since I'm usually very careful and not sure if it really is spam or something else, I've flagged it for moderator attention.

Was this the right choice or should I flag things like this as spam in the future? Or maybe I'm overreacting in the first place because at second glance it doesn't seem that bad?

Comment: Well, *excessive self promotion* is somewhat different from *spam*.  If you are fairly certain that the post is spam, flag it as such. If you are unsure, then raise a custom mod flag. In general, if the user is posting relevant answers but adding link to his site in his answers and if the answers can still stand (are valid, and answer the question) even after the link is removed, then raise a custom mod flag. So yes, I think you did the right thing. Also, if you see someone posting links to his blog/ website in "valid" answers, feel free to drop a comment about ESP

Comment: I love Meta effect: I searched to edit those questions in order to remove links, and all the questions of the user have already been updated, linking to Meta and explaning why he shouldn't do that. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind that probably would've been more suitable as an answer, given its length and that is completely answers the question

Comment: @Tas - Honestly, when I started out, I wasn't planning on writing an answer :)  (had to rush to a meeting and I thought that I wouldn't have enough time)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, the **spam** flag says:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation](/help/promotion).

If you have no reason to believe the user is affiliated with that site (and neither do I at the moment), then flagging as spam is not appropriate. However, it's clear that this kind of behaviour is undesirable. Those links have nothing to do with the answer and should be edited out (I have done so for a few posts). As a <2k user, also given the state of the Suggested Edits queue, that's not an appealing option.

I would leave a comment asking the user not to do this again, but such a comment carries a lot more weight when preceded by the words **Moderator Note:**. So your action, a custom moderator flag, is the right course of action here (as confirmed by TheLostMind ♦).

Note that the latest answer by the user (posted ±10 minutes after this question, so they might have been aware of this issue) does not contain any link to said website.

Comment: Uh, when I feel like trolling and post some random spam links to spam sites I never heard of myself, does that not count as spam? And I'm pretty certain that promoting a site always has a reason that one could call an "affiliation".

Comment: The reason that user isn't posting links to that site any more is more likely because of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026194/java-assign-button-arrays/45026668#comment77027357_45026668).

Comment: @Bergi *technically* it's abusive behaviour (the other red flag). But there has been some discussion to [merge them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345332/4751173) anyway.

Comment: @DavidG or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025652/how-can-i-get-current-connection-url-in-spring-jdbc/45026363#comment77029391_45026363) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025908/converting-binary-value-to-downloadable-zipfile/45026290#comment77030444_45026290).

Comment: So, you're spamming a user with comments to get them to stop spamming? Interesting approach.

Comment: Thanks to you and @TheLostMind for clearing things up. I noticed too, that the user hasn't posted a link in his newest answer. It seems like the actions have already been effective.