# What action should be taken on an answer making opinionated statements about the subject of the question and linking to a blog for more?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, triage

I am right now looking at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16537301) below:
[image: Answer]

I marked it as Not An Answer.

The question was about some trouble implementing captcha. I have zero knowledge about this thing. The answer instead of answering the question, was doing negative advertisement of a Google product (and maybe positive advertisement of his own blog). The answer talks more about laws instead of giving a solution.

In my understanding, it is not bad to mention negative points about some technology. For a question "Why this specific query is taking too long in MS SQL Server?" someone may answer:

> This is a case of xyz. As per documents from MS (link here), it is
>   handled [this] way by the SQL server which causes a performance hit. Oracle
>   on other hand handles it in [this] way which ultimately improves
>   performance. IMO Oracle is always better than MS SQL server.

This looks like a valid answer even though there is again *some* advertisement part in it.

But look at the one below:

> Microsoft is shit. Not only SQL Server, look at any product. It does
>   not work at all. Sluggish, buggy. Leave it. Oracle is great.

Both sample answers above are saying the same fact, but the first one is more technical and the other is more an advertisement.

With this in mind, I decided to flag that specific answer as Not An Answer. Is this a correct decision?

Another concern is about it being spam. The author of the answer is actually advertising his own blog. Can this be spam then?

Comment: It's a rant and has no business on SO. I'd flag it as abusive. For the same reason outlined [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317611/563532). Much like gibberish, it's a deliberate attempt at derailing the Q&A, and is *inappropriate for respectful discourse*.

Comment: Answer deleted by 3 20K-ers

Comment: The rant on their answer is almost as big as the one on their blog.

Comment: Smells like sugar-coated self-promotion. I especially love that "Americans and foreigners" bit.

Comment: If it's slave labor to identify the subject of pictures without pay, what about answering questions on Stack Overflow without pay? ;)

Comment: Presumably you scratched out the username so that the user could not be identified, but did it in a manner that provides zero obfuscation. Why bother?

Comment: @Aaroninus: I scratched out the username because I see it done on some meta posts. I am not sure why or even if this is necessary. About zero obfuscation you must be mentioning the link, right? That link was anyway necessary so that readers of this question should go there and see complete post if necessary.

Comment: @AmitJoshi No, "zero obfuscation" means that the attempt at hiding the username completely failed because the semi-transparent "ink" covering only parts of the name did almost nothing to keep it from being readable by a human eye. (Perhaps the link revealed it previously anyway, but now the question has been completely removed, yet the user is still discoverable with your image.)

Comment: @CPerkins: Ohh, ok. So basically, should I try to hide the identity of other user in question whenever I post something about him on meta? Or is it better if I ask separate question on this under [discussion] so that this could be guideline for others as well?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Though off topic, one is forced upon you the other is a choice.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No, these kinds of captchas are not "forced upon you"; you can simply *not use* the site which wants you to solve the captcha. Invoking slavery to describe a captcha is hyperbole that belittles the issue of true slavery.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's not always an option to not use. You asked for difference, I gave it. Didn't talk about slavery in any way.

Comment: @AmitJoshi  I see your other question about hiding the identity of a poster--That is a great question of itself. But after reading both that question and your last comment here, I don't think you perceived the point of Mike's original comment and my response. _We were not saying whether you should choose to do so or not_, but if you do decided to hide or obscure the identity of the poster, then at least take care to do a complete, thorough and effective job. The red lines you scribbled over the poster's username are **ineffective**, because the name is still completely readable.

Comment: @CPerkins: I understand that the way I tried to hide the identity of the poster in this question is ineffective. As I said, I just copied the idea of scratching the user name from other posts and was unaware about the reason and hence was not serious enough. As I understand this in details now, I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This at least qualifies as NAA, so you can (and did) flag it as such and let the queue deal with it.
The mention of slave labor and the global atmosphere of the rant elects it for an abusive flag too.

Now, my main concern would be that they advertised their own blog posts. While sort of within the boundaries of the rules (proper disclosure) this is extremely fishy in this situation.

In the end, if I encountered this post, I would probably have cast a moderator flag reading:

> This is more an offensive rant rather than an answer. Plus, the unsolicited advertising makes me unsure whether or not this is spam.

Comment: *"...the global atmosphere of the rant elects it for an abusive flag too."* Wait, so, if he would have just said Americans, and not "Americans and foreigners", it wouldn't have been abusive? :-p

Comment: @CodyGray nono, the global warming that affects the atmosphere is an hoax, and it's totally foreigners fault (specially Chinese foreigners).