# Should I hide the identity of other user while asking question or answer about that user on meta?

Tags: discussion, users, rules

Recently, I asked this question on meta: [What action should be taken on an answer making opinionated statements about the subject of the question and linking to a blog for more?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351303/5779732)

The question contains an image (screen capture) of an answer on Stack Overflow.

I am reading meta posts since many days. Some of the posts contains similar images  of question or answer by other user. I observed some of them strike (scratch) the name of OP in screen shot. So, I did same in above case.

I neither know why I should do this nor if this is necessary at all.

Apart from screen shot, many times it is necessary to provide the link to original post for multiple reasons. With that link, identity of OP can anyway be tracked. I guess Moderators can track the identity even after original post is deleted. Considering this, it does not make sense attempting to hide the identity of OP.

Not posting the screen shot of posts (as link could be anyway provided) does not look good option as the post may be deleted in future and in that case, question on meta become meaningless for new users reading it.

- Is it necessary to hide the identity of OP?
- Why?
- If yes, how should I do it in proper way?

**About comments so far:**

- @NathanOliver: Meta is not for making user shame and that was never my intention. I agree that meta should be only involved when needed.
- @BSMP: I understand screen shot or link to the original post should be only posted if exact text of post matters while answering a question on Meta.

Comment: have you hear about the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: One thing you never want to do is shame a user. If you see a user doing what you think is bad behavior then use a custom flag (mod flag) and let them know about it. No reason to get meta involved.

Comment: There's some good discussion about this over on Meta.SE in ["Should any Meta post that calls out a user by name be deleted, not just downvoted?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289909/should-any-meta-post-that-calls-out-a-user-by-name-be-deleted-not-just-downvote)

Comment: Links and screenshots of a question are necessary when the meta post is about the question itself and not about a specific user's behavior. A good example would be questions about failed audits: if someone is asking, "How is this a tool request" we actually do need to see the exact text of the question in order to answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Is it necessary to hide the identity of OP?

**Yes, but it's unavoidable at times.**

The biggest reason to hide the OP's identity is to avoid unnecessary or unjust retribution of any kind, known colloquially as [the Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect).

> Why?

**Even if it's unintentional, it can have lasting consequences.**

Since bans are tied to the reception of one's posts, suddenly having a surge of votes to the negative of your posts doesn't bode well for your chances of staying *un*banned.  Worse still, the ban may be unjustly applied, as there have been cases in which members of the community have routinely voted in a way to avoid detection from the automatic serial voting script in an effort to punish a user.

> If yes, how should I do it in proper way?

**Focus on the actual problem you see, not the person.**

It's easy to tie a name to an issue, and to attach labels to someone who did something, but that neither solves the issue nor makes the person you have a problem with suddenly learn from their ways.  I say again that it can be unavoidable because, if you deal with a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) or [specific-answer](/questions/tagged/specific-answer), you're drawing *immediate* attention to a person or people.

So, I'd recommend the following if you have to call it out:

- **Objectively describe the issue** and don't mention names here.
- ***Never* use meta as a way to notify moderators about a user's behaviors**; any flagging that needs to be done should be done by yourself.  All we're going to do is rally against what we see as "bad behavior", and we are quite well-tooled to do so.
- If it has to be about someone specific, **invite them to Meta** to discuss the issue as well.  Hearing both sides of the story makes it seem less like public ridicule and more like amelioration.

Comment: +1 for the fancy word at the end :)

Comment: A french user would not be lost reading this word, i can tell :)