# When, and when not to disclose names when discussing a users actions on meta

Tags: discussion, meta, privacy

Often, on meta, we discuss the action of a specific user (a question, answer, comment or other action). Sometimes, their name is redacted, and sometimes it isn't.

When should we disclose the name of a user we're discussing? And when should we protect their identity?

What considerations should I make when disclosing links to posts, comments or chat logs?

Comment: Why does it ever have to be about the user? We aren't in the public user shaming business.

Comment: @TinyGiant I believe accountability is important, especially when we're discussing things like closing questions (where a user might have worked long and hard on), or other moderation efforts. But note that I post this question because I'm truly not sure, and I'm wondering where the community stands on it, not to push my own view.

Comment: [Highly relevant.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289913/141525)

Comment: Shouldn't this really be about 'when and when not to link posts'? The posts provide an easy avenue to disclosing the user's 'name' and are much more likely to generate adverse 'meta-effect'.

Comment: @Jeeped It's not only about linking questions, also about things like naming moderators, naming people reviewing or commenting, etc. The way that users are named most often is by linking a post, though. In fact, the main inspirations for writing this question were a post where a moderator shared a non-anonimized screenshot (not link) with comments, and a post discussing the actions of a moderator on multiple posts.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351373/5779732

Answer (score 42):

#### By default, anonymize.

> Often, on meta, we discuss the ***action*** of a specific user

Action. The keyword in this discussion is the reason the default needs to be anonymize. We want to discuss the *actions* and not the *user* specifically. I cannot think of a legitimate reason for a post to be about the user rather than the action.

You should *always* strive to redact names. Even if it is trivial to figure out who you're talking about, you should focus on the action and not offer up the name.

#### We're not here to air dirty laundry, we're here to help improve the site.

Discussing users doesn't help us improve. Discussing actions and how they affect the site does.

It might take a few extra seconds to redact names, maybe even a minute or two. But it's better to put forth that effort to help focus your question than to start a witch hunt against a user who likely just made a mistake.

#### If a user is doing something wrong, don't post it on Meta to name and shame them. Flag it.

You can bring the *action* to Meta if it's questionable, but if someone's doing something wrong? Flag it, let the mods handle it in private without humiliating the user. It's respectful to the other user, and if there's more to the story than normal users can see, then it can be taken into account.

Comment: I can imagine in cases where a chatroom is involved, for example SOCVR, a link to the transcript is provided. That instantly reveals a user. I would not go that far to anonymize those but some extra care to not blame the user helps to have a rational discussion.

Comment: @rene Yes, that could be a case... As long as the post strives hard for focusing on the action(s) and not the user(s) I doubt anyone would fault them. Otherwise the best you could anonymize that would be a screenshot, and if it's a long chain in chat... Way easier to link the transcript.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think the context of a users action is important when deciding to disclose or not to disclose a name.

If the user was serving a public role, I'd say it's appropriate to name that user, since their actions affect the site at large.

In this context, I consider the following things to be public roles:

- Moderating the site, either through one of the review queues, by voting to close or reopen questions or by participating in one of the moderation chatrooms (SOCVR, Charcoal, others)
- Participating in public discussions (anything tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)) on Meta Stack Overflow
- Elections or other public events

I think in these public roles, accountability takes priority over privacy, and thus, naming the specific person and holding them accountable is justified.

In contrast, I consider the following roles on Stack Overflow to be more private, and I would consider naming or linking a user here *bad form*:

- Posting single questions, answers, or comments on Stack Overflow
- Chatting in chatrooms not oriented towards site moderation

I consider all moderators and SO employees to be public figures on Stack Overflow, and thus think naming them here is appropriate when discussing their actions.

Note that often enough, you can infer which user is talked about, by using context or information provided in the question. In my opinion, this doesn't justify linking and naming the user in question.

This also means that when discussing specific questions, answers, and/or comments, you should not link, but screenshot + redact instead (with possible added freehand circles).

<sub>Of course, screenshotting also partly prevents the meta effect from happening, which is often desired.</sub>

<sub>Note that these are my personal preferences. I'd like to hear other opinions</sub>

Comment: [Moderate the post, not the user](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-moderate-post-not-user) is obviously a one-sided contract. Sad.

Comment: @rene According to the downvotes on this answer, apparently not. Normally, I don't like getting downvotes, but on this answer, I truly don't mind. I think the _only discuss actions_ approach is valid, though I think accountability has it's influence on the validity of moderation. If you can hold me accountable at any time for my close votes, you know I will cast them with care, and only when deserved.

Comment: I probably go wrong again here but following that reasoning you could argue up and down votes should also be public so they are cast with care and only when deserved.

Comment: <[insert mandatory downvote comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s)>

Comment: @rene Well, that's a discussion that is had often (together with the one about commenting on votes). I think making all voters public would be interesting, and would perhaps improve the site (probably wouldn't lead to that much revenge downvotes because they would be public too), but I know that's just not going to happen.